# Normalize a single-table database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I am currently working on designing the database for a weather information management system. The whole database can be represented by a single table with columns for `humidity`, `temperature`, `heat index`, `pressure`, `UV index`, `wind speed` and `wind direction` with the composite primary key of `Date` and `City`.

How can I normalize my database by dividing it into more than one table?

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. You ask how to normalize. Normalization to higher NFs requires knowing FDs. Also just saying you want to normalize tells us nothing without a target NF. If you use the word "normalize" you should know that. What NF & what are the FDs, or if you were not given them, what is your best effort about what they are & why? So far you are asking us to rewrite your textbook & apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

City/location should be one table by itself.

then use a FK to link over to that for each observation
if each observation always has the same (full) load of values - then keep it the way you describe - if you get observations of different types at different times, then break out each type of observation into its own table.

Comment: Thanks! Will there be only two tables in the database? 

PS the information will be updated daily(on the basis of date).

Comment: As @Randy wrote, if your weather measurements/observations are somehow separated (e.g. as suggested: based on time), then you may benefit from placing them in separate tables. E.g. if wind speed and direction comes from a separate instrument, than the rest of readings/measurements/estimates, and not all locations do have those instruments, you could have the wind parameters in a separate table, only filled for those locations, which do have those readings.

Comment: Possibly there are other things you could extract to a separate table. E.g. if the `heat index` can be determined based on `temperature` (e.g. for temperatures between 25 and 40 deg. Celsius, the heat index is "Hot", then you could have a table defining the heat index temperature ranges and their names). If the `UV index` is a textual indication (not an actual numeric UV index), then you could also extract those to a "dictionary" table (as with locations).

Comment: @Hilarion Normalization to higher NFs does not introduce new column names or values, eg ids. Your '"dictionary" table' designs are not the result of normalization.

Comment: Randy (& @SMFarjad): Since the database is starting out as one table, observations can't appear separately--taking the question at face value to record the variables at a given date in the obvious way. That's artificial, but if you're going to address real-life issues that can't arise under the artificial but given conditions you should say so. Also you don't say why you are doing what you are doing--and a 6NF design (separate readings) only needs a date-city  table with no reading(s) if there is a requirement to store date-city pairs without a reading--another contrary requirement.

Comment: @philipxy: I was not suggesting introducing new columns. If you are referring to what I wrote for `UV index`, then I was just giving options, depending on what the `UV index` actually already is in the table being normalized - it can be a numerical index already (according to formal definition of the UV index) or a human readable information (which - from what I understand - is also commonly used). The domain knowledge could be used here to have effective normalization, not just a formal one. One way or another, the question is generic and we can't be sure if we're asked for formal NF-s.

Comment: @Hilarion The question asks about normalizing, and you're not talking about normalization, and "effective normalization" is misuse of the term. I repeat myself.

Comment: I understand you. I may be wrong, but the question may not necessarily be about the same meaning of the term "normalization", i.e. what I called "formal normalization". The word "normalization" has also different meanings, used also in the RDBMS-related contexts (i.e. applying any kind of norm, not necessarily DB-related, as it may e.g. be coming from the domain modeled by the DB, or be bringing it to a state considered "normal"). One could say, that attributing the term normalization to just one meaning, where it already had other (more broad) one, was a misuse on the Codd's side. :)